# Find with proof the number of units in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find with proof the number of units in the ring $$R=\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$$

Since $\gcd(5,8,9)=1$, by Chinese Remainder Theorem, I get $R=\mathbb{Z}_{360}$

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{360}$ is not a field, not all elements has inverse. Then I get nowhere from here. Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: Hint: How many units in each of $\mathbb Z_8, \mathbb Z_9,\,\mathbb Z_5$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Do we need ring tag here? :)

Comment: $R$ is already in the best possible form. It does not really help to write it $\mathbb{Z}_{360}$. It is easy to see that the unit group is are $\mathbb{Z}_8^*\times\mathbb{Z}_9^*\times \mathbb{Z}_5^*$. So you just have to compute $\phi(8)\phi(9)\phi(5)$. You might want to use or observe that $\phi(p^\alpha)=p^\alpha-p^{\alpha-1}$ for any prime $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$ is a unit if and only if $x$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z_8$, $y$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z_9$ and $z$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: ooh, thanks, I manage to prove the hint.

Answer (score 2):

The number of units in $\Bbb Z_{360}$ is the number of positive integers less than $360$ that are coprime to it. That is, $\phi(360)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

As an alternate approach, it is simpler to count the number of units in $\Bbb Z_8,\Bbb Z_9,\Bbb Z_5$. If $(x,y,z)$ is a unit of $R$, what can you say about $x,y,z$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** An element $a$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_n$ if and only if gcd$(a,n)=1$.

It might be easier if you count the numbers of units in $\mathbb Z_8, \mathbb Z_9$ and $\mathbb Z_5$.